# Placing animation drawable based on touch

Tags: android

I have created a relative layout with couple of buttons at the bottom of the screen. The reast of the screen is blank. I want to place/drag images where user touches the screen. I am between 2 options. These images have animation so I was going to use animationdrawable

1- Use the activity OnTouchEvent to make sure the click is within empty area and start placing/moving images around

2- Create a surfaceview in this area and implements its touch events and deal with a  surface view.

What do you think?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, both of those ways should work and i think it is optional choise.

Here i think i would go on the onTouchListener because that all of your view is writen with xml, using surfaceView now will make the code complicate.

I think you should take it aldo because it is writen for you. This will make your life way easier.
You are using drawable, stored as integer in R and making surfaceView will be difficult because you will need to use the SurfaceView, bitmaps inside him and the xml.

To get the press you will use onThouchListiner anyway, stleast when you do it, you will make your life way easier

Comment: Perfect that was my thought too but I wanted to make sure that I am not missing some performance hit or something.. Thank you

Comment: actually, you should know that it does not matter. when you compile,the xml is transfer to java code. the only thing that matter is the compilation time, compiling the xml takes time but for the running and preformance it is the same. though you need to know that :)